# 1080p upload to youtube?

Tags: video, camera, ipad, youtube, quality

I just captured a video with my new iPad, then used the iPad's built-in tools to upload it to youtube.  I selected "high quality" but [it appears to be only a 720p video on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uV_eYPXEbVc) (caution: kids and baby chicks herein).

Is there a way to upload a 1080p video from the iPad to Youtube?

Comment: I'm seeing a 720p version available now, maybe there's just a delay for some server-side encoding? The 1080p version could be on the way

Comment: @KyleCronin It did go up to 720p, but not to 1080p, unless the processing queue is over 24 hours...

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the YouTube iOS app? You may need to change a few settings first, but I believe the YouTube app supports full quality videos - including 4K. Apple's built-in uploader from the share menu doesn't work that well.

In the YouTube iOS app, click your user image, then on the window that slides up, select Settings. Scroll down to uploads and confirm that full quality is selected for upload quality. Press the X on the top left to return to the main part of the app.

You may now press the camera button (next to the search button) on the top bar. It will ask for appropriate permissions. Try uploading from there and see if it works for you.

[image: Top bar]

(I just tested this method and can confirm HD+ resolutions - also, I just noticed that this was a really necro'd post.)

Answer (score 1):

Youtube Capture used to do just that perfectly. Joins videos with minimal re-encoding. Though:

- It crashes a lot on iOS 10.
- It won't run on iOS 11.

Would love to find a free alternative. So far, I tried free editors that pop up in a search, but each one I tried was horrible.

**update**: YouTube itself can now do it, so @drivec's answer should do it. It still doesn't join clips, though.